# TFS 2015 Express is not accepting my windows credentials to log to the local server

Tags: tfs

I'm installing TFS 2015 Express. I can't get past the configuration process. I'm getting the Windows Security popup. I've typed my username and password. My username is being recognized but not my password.

Which credentials TFS is expecting? I'm entering the info I use to login to Windows.

[image]

Thanks for helping

Comment: You must use service accounts to install Team Foundation Server, check https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/requirements#accounts

Answer (score 0):

You could use local Admin account or Domain account to install TFS2015 Express.Try below ways to narrow down the issue:

- When you run the `tfs_express.exe` to install, right click the .exe
  and select **run as administrator**.
- Disable your antivirus software or add the .exe in trust list.
- Remove your account info which stored in **Credential Manager** (Control
  Panel-All Control Panel Items-Credential Manager-Windows Manager) and
  try again

[image]